# Mitmproxy vs BurpSuite

Tags: linux, kali-linux, testing

I searched in google a lot, but I didn't find any solution. I know mitmproxy, but I don't know burpsuite. Is both same, or do they perform different tasks? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mitmproxy & Burpsuit are functionally same.

mitmproxy is a TUI based and Burpsuit is a GUI (Java) based, you have a community edition for Burpsuit. From new user perspective, Burpsuit is easier to use and mitmproxy is complex to use.

Comment: mitmproxy is the coolest and easiest mitm proxy out there